# how to authenticate web interface listning in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I am running mongodb on port `27017`. So, I can see `web interface listening` on `http://myipaddress:28017` But it is open. How can I authenticate it? So, only an authenticate person can view this page?

Answer (score 2):

**If security is configured** for a mongod instance, authentication is required for a client to access the http interface **from another machine** (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface). You can not use authentication for clients that access from the same machine.

If you want to turn off the http interface start mongo using the --nohttpinterface option